# install php7.4 on ubuntu 16.04 - Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

I am trying to install php7.4 and related packages with below commands

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y software-properties-common\
    && add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php7.4
```

I get the below message

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package php7.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4'
```

on searching with

```
apt-cache search php7
```

I see that only 7.0 related packages are available

```
php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
php7.0-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php7.0-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.0-common - documentation, examples and common module for PHP
php7.0-curl - CURL module for PHP
```

I am confused why I am not getting the newer versions as 7.3, 7,4 and 8 should be the only ones available today. How can I get php7.4 packages?

Comment: Why not use ready-made PHP docker images? https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Comment: Thanks for the comment, This is a live application, so I am not keen on changing the entire dockerfile to upgrade to php7.4. The above dockerfile is simplified to show only PHP installation.

Comment: `apt search php7` on 16.04 only shows packages for 7.0. 7.4 isn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Since Ubuntu 16.04 reached "End of Standard Support", packages for it were removed from the PPA.

---

You might want to read this: https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1567

> In April 2021, Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial will reach End of Standard Support and will be available only as a paid option through Ubuntu Extended Security Maintenance.
>
> What does it mean for DEB.SURY.ORG PPAs?
>
> - The packages for Ubuntu 16.04 will be deleted shortly after the EoL/EoSS is announced, usually at the same time as the next PHP release is published because it's not possible to build the packages any more.
> - The packages for Ubuntu 16.04 will be available via PHP LTS by Freexian paid program. This is cheaper option than previously announced Private dedicated repositories.

Comment: Thank you for this info.As much as I suspected 16.04 is removed from ppa, as per Ubuntu site information 16.04 has not reached its end of life.  Unsure how that works for the ppa packages. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's not EOL, but "End of Standard Support". Ubuntu 16.04 is now in the ESM period (https://ubuntu.com/security/esm). Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget tar make
RUN wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.33.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
RUN tar xzf php-7.4.33.tar.gz
RUN cd php-7.4.33
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install gcc
RUN apt-get -y install expect
RUN apt-get -y install pkg-config
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install -y libsqlite3-dev
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install -y libxml2-dev
RUN ./php-7.4.33/configure
RUN make
RUN make install

CMD ["/bin/bash"]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

**Install PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 20.04**

NOTE: Ubuntu 20.04 ships with PHP 7.4 in its upstream repositories. Just install it and the extensions you with the apt package manager.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php php-cli php-fpm php-json php-common php-mysql php-zip php-gd php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath
```

Confirm PHP version:

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Mar 26 2020 20:24:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

**Install PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04/16.04**

*Step 1: Add PHP PPA Repository*
We’ll add ppa:ondrej/php PPA repository which has the latest build packages of PHP.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

*Step 2: Install PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04/19.04/16.04*
Install PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04/19.04/16.04 using the command:

```
sudo apt -y install php7.4
```

Check version installed:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.4.0beta4 (cli) (built: Aug 28 2019 11:41:49) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.0beta4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Use the next command to install additional packages:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-xxx
```

Example:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-{bcmath,bz2,intl,gd,mbstring,mysql,zip,common}
```

PHP configurations related to Apache is stored in /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini

I hope my experience help you guys

Comment: With all the respect, this is not your experience, but content copy-pasted from another website :)

Comment: I agree with @ZoliSzabó. This is a standard response on anything related to installing PHP on ubuntu without understanding the real question here.